# 2 files, same first column, one file has a lot of repeats with different data

Tags: sorting, unix, join, sed

**File1:**

```
000333999:dat:data:dataa
999333000:da:daa:daata
939494092:data:data:dataa
```

Lines like that

**File2:**

```
000333999:999303
000333999:3243257224
000333999:23552
939494092:921942
000333999:243252
939494092::3243257224
939494092:243252
939494092:332432
000333999:332432
000333999:353252
939494092:299
000333999:342342351142
939494092:392
000333999:3253251
000333999:532322
000333999:2324325
```

I would like all lines to match together in a file like this:

```
000333999:dat:data:dataa:999303:2324325:532322:3253251:342342351142:353252:332432
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Ok, and what you have try so far?

Comment: Figuring out how those first two lists of gibberish combine to form the third seems to require slightly more OCD than I have.

Comment: I have tried "join -t ':' <(sort file2) <(sort file1) >file3"  however that doesn't really work for what I need! Im sorry! I am not good with this type of things!

Comment: "join -t ':' <(sort file2) <(sort file1) >file3" will work if second file has only 1 line to match, but second file has lots of different lines to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ':' '{sub( /^[^:]*/, "",V=$0);Anchor[$1]=Anchor[$1] V} END{ for( Data in Anchor) print Data Anchor[Data]}' File1 File2
```

Order of lines output may be different